# Get User By User Email From SQLite

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sqlite

Here's my getUser mothod :

```
public User getUser(String Email) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();


    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + DBContract.Users.TABLE_NAME
            + " WHERE " + DBContract.Users.COL_EMAIL + " = " + Email;
    try {
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

        User user = new User();

        // Read data, I simplify cursor in one line
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            // Get imageData in byte[]. Easy, right?
            user.setUserID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Users._ID))));
            user.setUserName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Users.COL_NAME)));
            user.setUserImage(cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Users.COL_IMAGE)));
            user.setUserPassword(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Users.COL_PASSWORD)));
            user.setUserEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Users.COL_EMAIL)));
            user.setUserLocation(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Users.COL_LOCATION)));


        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return user;

    } catch (SQLException e) {

    }
    return null;
}
```

User Profile Fragment where i call the getUser:

```
public class UserHomeFragment extends Fragment {
DBHelper dbHelper;
User user;
ImageView userImageView;
TextView userNameTexView;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_profile_home_fragment, container, false);

    dbHelper = new DBHelper(v.getContext());
    user = new User();
    userImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.userimg);
    userNameTexView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_name);


    Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    assert extras != null;
    String userEmail = extras.getString("userEmail");


    user = dbHelper.getUser(userEmail);

  // Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(userImage, 0, userImage.length);
  // userImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
   userNameTexView.setText(user.getUserName());

    return v;
}}
```

Why the getUser return null ? I've checked there are users at the user's table .

Error Massage:Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.arfni.ayafinal.model.User.getUserName()' on a null object reference

Comment: why don't you want to debug your code? check that your method returns something. And Error massage is hilarious

Comment: Trust me i was trying to solve the problem since yesterday , and the debug showed me that the getUser returns null. But i couldn't solve the error .@ViktorYakunin

Comment: It’s throwing an exception hence the null. Email needs to be in single quotes. “ = ‘“ + Email + “‘“ As email has an @ symbol in it, it’s breaking the SQL parser as its not realizing email is a string. This is effectively what you wrote: WHERE Email = andrew.finnell@gmail.com when you want WHERE Email = ‘andrew.finnell@gmail.com’ and perhaps use LIKE instead of =.

Comment: thankk you !! u saved my life @AndrewTFinnell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are encountering is two-fold.

The prime error is that you need to enclose a string value in quotes otherwise it may be considered as a keyword or an entity (e.g. a table or a column name) or it may cause a syntax error. In short the SQL will not execute and result in an exception.

The compounding error is that the exception is caught and thus the exception is ignored result in no Cursor being created and returned and hence the Cursor variable is never set, so it will be null and then when you then try to close the Cursor it will be null as it outside the scope of the null check.

Furthermore, you also have a potential issue in that if the cursor is not null but is empty, then the `moveToFirst` will not move to the first row as there isn't a first row to move to. This is indicated by the `moveToFirst` method returning false. The returned value isn't checked in your code so when you attempt to get the data an exception will occur (along the lines of try to read Index 0 when there are 0 rows) this too being trapped and perhaps leading to confusion.

I'd suggest replacing the getUser method with the following :-

```
public User getUser(String Email) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + DBContract.Users.TABLE_NAME
            + " WHERE " + DBContract.Users.COL_EMAIL + " = " + Email;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    User user = new User();

    // Read data, I simplify cursor in one line
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        // Get imageData in byte[]. Easy, right?
        user.setUserID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Users._ID))));
        user.setUserName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Users.COL_NAME)));
        user.setUserImage(cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Users.COL_IMAGE)));
        user.setUserPassword(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Users.COL_PASSWORD)));
        user.setUserEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Users.COL_EMAIL)));
        user.setUserLocation(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Users.COL_LOCATION)));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return user;
}
```

#### Notes

- If the SQL fails then the exception stop the App. (i.e try/catch has bee removed).
- Should the SQL result in nothing being extracted then an empty cursor is returned (you do not get a null Cursor except if you force it), as such the check for a null Cursor has been removed, rather than moving it so that it will not result in an exception.
- user will either be null (no rows in the Cursor) or the user will be populated so there is no need to return null.